# My flex/yacc program compiles differently on two different linux machines

Tags: gcc, yacc, compilation, lexical-analysis

One one machine, everything compiles fine.  On another machine, it complains about the -ly option when I use gcc to create the output file.  If I remove the -ly option, then it makes the program, but then it runs differently.  What's happening.  How can I get the program to run correctly on this linux machine?

Answer (score 1):

You should check to see if you have the same flex/bison versions...

Answer (score 1):

YACC program options (and generated output) vary from OS to OS. Bison might be more consistent.